# Dell H700 Controller, BBU present but not charging...?

Tags: dell, h700, bbu

I have a new Dell R710 with a H700+BBU controller that is not charging. 
Last week when I was looking at performance stats (and trying to figure out why write policy had changed from write-back to write-through) I realized the BBU was not charged. The overall stats available through MegaCli appear to indicate the BBU is OK but it wont charge.
I kicked off a manual learn cycle, waited a couple days, reseated the BBU, and nothing seems to get the BBU to a charging or charged state.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -a0

BBU status for Adapter: 0

BatteryType: BBU
Voltage: 2960 mV
Current: 0 mA
Temperature: 27 C

BBU Firmware Status:

  Charging Status              : None
  Voltage                      : OK
  Temperature                  : OK
  Learn Cycle Requested        : No
  Learn Cycle Active           : No
  Learn Cycle Status           : OK
  Learn Cycle Timeout          : No
  I2c Errors Detected          : No
  Battery Pack Missing         : No
  Battery Replacement required : No
  Remaining Capacity Low       : Yes
  Periodic Learn Required      : No
  Transparent Learn            : No

Battery state: 

GasGuageStatus:
  Fully Discharged        : Yes
  Fully Charged           : No
  Discharging             : Yes
  Initialized             : Yes
  Remaining Time Alarm    : Yes
  Remaining Capacity Alarm: Yes
  Discharge Terminated    : No
  Over Temperature        : No
  Charging Terminated     : No
  Over Charged            : No

Relative State of Charge: 0 %
Charger Status: Unknown
Remaining Capacity: 0 mAh
Full Charge Capacity: 1700 mAh
isSOHGood: Yes

Exit Code: 0x00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell shipped me a new BBU, replaced it and now the battery state is charging. The issue was a bad BBU. controller is OK.

Answer (score 4):

This is a new 710? Call up Dell, get them to ship you a new unit within your SLA. Swap drives into new unit, send old one back.

Comment: Hi Mark, this is a new server but the H700 controller was purchased separately from Dell.  I'm already working with Dell support but was hoping the community might have seen this issue and have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an operating system installed, there is a piece of software from Dell called OMSA (Open Manage Server Administrator). This can be used to do a plethora of different administrative functions not the least of which is a battery recondition function. This takes a bit but it might revive your dead battery. Hope this helps.

Comment: OMSA uses MegaCli to perform all of those functions.

Comment: Dell shipped me a new BBU, replaced it and now the battery state is charging.  looks like it was a bad BBU.